# How to reset elementary OS settings to default without reinstalling?

Tags: release-freya, settings

I am using elementary OS Freya. How to reset elementary OS settings to default without reinstalling, and without using [Timeshift](http://www.elementarynow.com/applications/timeshift/)?

There is no option like <kbd>Restore Default Settings</kbd> under about:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

#### The following commands effectively take the same action a reset button would.

You could *try* to use `gsettings`.

First, create a file with all the keys in it:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep '^\S*' > keys.txt
```

then loop through that file and reset each key

```
while read line; do echo $line; gsettings reset-recursively $line; done <keys.txt
```

This resets all the settings (hopefully).

Comment: Hey @Tim nice, I will try and then accept it :) Is there any way through GUI?

Comment: @Ravan no, no gui method

Comment: after running this code and restarting the OS, still I dont see `Restore Default Settings`

Comment: @WOEITG No, this command *does* reset them.

Comment: So you mean after running these commands, I should see `Restore Default Settings` ? so what am I missing? I am using elementary OS 0.3.2 freya

Comment: @WOEITG No. Those commands reset all settings.

Comment: This is just strange. 4 votes for a solution that doesn't work.

Comment: @WOEITG I actually made a meta post about that: http://meta.elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/163/please-ensure-the-answer-you-are-voting-for-does-answer-the-question

Comment: @user3: wrong, and by wrong I mean right. What I mean is that your answer works on eOS. I just had to `awk '{print $1}'` the file before feeding it to the loop though. But you saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

Lewis G's approach worked for me on Loki, but needed a bit of tinkering. It also wound up being quite a bit slower than necessary, as gsettings list-recursively repeated a bunch of keys. Here's a one-liner that should do it all. It skips the temp file and runs much faster by removing repeated lines.

```
for line in `gsettings list-recursively | grep '^\S*' |awk '{ print  $1 }' | uniq`; do gsettings reset-recursively $line; done
```

Answer (score 2):

In System Settings > About there is a button "Restore Default Settings".

This will reset all system gsettings keys. It will not reset settings for apps or delete any of your personal data.

Edit: Ah my mistake. This feature hasn't landed as a stable update yet.