# UI is messed up, how to restore the original?

Tags: user-interface

I have no idea what happened. All of a sudden applications on elementary started having white gaps and misplaced content. This happened after I tried to install GNOME Builder. Can some one help me out without needing to reinstall Elementary? Here are some images:

[image: screenshot 1]
[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset elementary OS settings to default without reinstalling?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/how-to-reset-elementary-os-settings-to-default-without-reinstalling)

Comment: @lemonslice I want to know how to fix it so it actually goes back to normal.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. It looks like he upgraded to a new version of Gtk+

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the screenshot, my best guess is that you've unknowingly upgraded your system to a newer version of Gtk+ that is incompatible with the elementary stylesheet. This makes Builder work, but it might cause issues with other apps.

To check which version of Gtk+ you have installed, you can run the Terminal command:

```
sudo apt-cache policy libgtk-3-0
```

You should see some output like:

```
libgtk-3-0:
  Installed: 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1
  Candidate: 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.18.9-1ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

This tells me that I have version `3.18.9` installed. This is the original version that ships with elementary OS.

If you have a newer version of Gtk+ (like `3.20`), you can either try to manually edit the stylesheet to fix issues yourself, switch to a stylesheet that supports whatever version of Gtk+ you've upgraded to, or try downgrading Gtk+ to the original version shipped with elementary OS.